# Search inside the view, if not found, how to set up no results behaviour?

Tags: views

All view need a No results behaviour, this applies to Courses list(view), information list(view) and activities list(view);please tell to how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Please set this at the field level or at the right corner at the views edit.

No Result Behaviour. If you want to set this with all the views than select All display at field level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Advanced configuration section of the views, you will find **NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR**, you can use the 'Add' button next to it to select **Global: Text area** option. Then add your no result description there.

[image]

FYI, this is for **Drupal 7**.